# I would like to Validate a SQL Statement and then return if its valid or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have made a stored proc and i would like it to return true of false depending if the SQL statement is valid.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckSQLStatement]
@SQL varchar(8000)
AS

SET NOEXEC ON
Exec @SQL 
SET NOEXEC OFF
```

This i what i have so far, when the statement is valid, in the SQL Server management studio, the results are ***Command(s) completed successfully.*** and if the statement i invalid it returns an error message, EG ***Incorrect syntax near 'Selec'.***

Firstly how can i return a Value True of false if statement is valid.

Secondly how can i return the invalid error message?

I was thinking something like:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckSQLStatement]
@SQL varchar(8000),
@IsValid bit OUTPUT,
@text NVARCHAR(1000)OUTPUT
AS

 SET NOEXEC ON
 Exec @SQL 
 SET NOEXEC OFF

Select @Isvalid
Select @Text
```

But i don't know how to set thos values?

Is there a better method?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is tagged with SQLServer 2008. If by any chance you can switch to SQLServer 2012, you could use the so-called "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL Language Service" and implement an extended stored proc to check your statement. See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this problem, too, and my solution involved

```
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
   BEGIN TRY
       ... execute sql
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
      WHILE @@TRANCOUNT > 0
         ROLLBACK

      ... check ERROR_*() functions
   END CATCH
```

Full TSQL code is on [my blog](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/checking-ms-sql-server-stored-procedures/), and there's an [app](http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/checking-ms-sql-server-objects/) for that.

Comment: This is not very directional an i don't know what i'm looking for?